# Is the definition of the derivative the same regardless in which function you place the limit variable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is this expression true?$$y(x) =\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$$

I'm taking the limit of h goes to 0 for y(x) and I got the latter equation. Can I just write y(x) = df(x)/dx?

Comment: The $d$ in $dx$ refers to infinitesimally small change, thus $h \rightarrow 0$ is the correct one.

Comment: Your two limits are the same. In the second limit, write $h = -t$. This flips all the signs and makes it into the first limit, using $t$ in place of $h$. The take-away point is that the limit $h \rightarrow 0$ doesn't care if $h$ is positive or negative as you "approach" zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two limits are indeed equivalent.

Let me provide a simple example where $f(x) = 6x$

$$\lim_{h->0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h->0}\frac{6(x+h)-6x}{h}=\lim_{h->0}\frac{6h}{h} = 6$$

$$\lim_{h->0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h} = \lim_{h->0}\frac{6x-6(x-h)}{h} = \lim_{h->0}\frac{6h}{h} = 6$$

Answer (score 0):

Your equation shows lim(h->inf) but I think you mean lim(h->0). In this case, a necessary and sufficient condition for the second equality in your equation is that the function is both left and right continuous at the point x.

In short, yes lim f(x+h)-f(x)/h = lim f(x)-f(x-h)/h as h->0 so long as f(x) is continuous, and indeed y(x)=d/dx f(x) by the definition of derivatives.